# postgres build json object with optional key value pair

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Below I have implemented a simple postgres notify trigger function, which
publishes the `OLD` and `NEW` record as a custom json object after an `insert` or `update` transaction.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test() 
    RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM pg_notify('test_chanel', json_build_object('new',row_to_json(NEW),'old',row_to_json(OLD))::text );
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

should emit

```
{
   "old":{...},
   "new":{...}
}
```

Problem is that OLD obviously does not exists for an `insert`. How can I make it optional?

Comment: `jsonb_strip_nulls()`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: it's typically not recommended to send a NOTIFY which a large payload.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the reply

could you provide an example on how to use jsonb_strip_nulls() here? I'm fairly new to postgres

Answer (score 0):

You can use automatic variable [`TG_OP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) inside trigger. With this variable your code should to look like

```
BEGIN
  IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
    PERFORM pg_notify('test_chanel', json_build_object('new',row_to_json(NEW));
  ELSEIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
    PERFORM pg_notify('test_chanel', json_build_object('new',row_to_json(NEW),'old',row_to_json(OLD))::text );
  ELSE
    PERFORM pg_notify('test_chanel', json_build_object(row_to_json(OLD))::text );
  END IF;
END;
```